# Delete file from folder in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to delete a file whose name is saved in `$category_image`. But the function `delete_files()` is not deleting.

```
public function deleteCategory($id,$category_image)
{
    $this->load->helper('file');
    //echo FCPATH.'/uploads/'.$category_image;

     delete_files(FCPATH.'/uploads/'.$category_image,false,false);die;
    //$this->load->model('AdminModel')->deleteCategory($id);
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747897/deleting-a-file-using-php-codeigniter

Comment: @Harshitkyal am I using correct path? The file is located at localhost/project/uploads

Comment: Syntax : delete_files($path[, $del_dir = FALSE[, $htdocs = FALSE]]) . delete_files('./path/to/directory/'); Right click on file you will get the path on properties. Copy that path in argument.

Comment: You can also use unlink($path);

Comment: I would check if the user as permissions to delete the file

Comment: Yes it has permission

Comment: Unlink() is working perfectly but not delete_files()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `delete_files()` is the wrong function to use. It is designed to "Deletes all files contained in the supplied directory path." -  not to delete a single file. The addition of a file name at the end of the path causes the function to fail.

Just use `unlink()`

```
unlink(FCPATH.'uploads/'.$category_image);die;
```

Note that the constant `FCPATH` already has a directory separator at the end so don't add another before `'uploads/'`.

Comment: what is FCPATH...? is that reserved keywords ?

Comment: @gumuruh, It is a string constant that is defined early in CI's startup. It is the full and absolute path (ending with a slash) to the folder that contains index.php e.g. `'/var/www/example.com/public/'`  Sorry for the slow reply. I haven't been here much lately.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys are looking for rest api unlink then

```php
     function delete_pres()
{
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
     unlink(FCPATH.'./prescriptions/'.$id);die;

     // if image on same location of code unlink(FCPATH.'../prescriptions/'.$id);die;
}

url : https://.../api/delete_pres?id=imagename.jpg
```